# Multiple Tasks in Windows Task Scheduler slow down PC significantly

Tags: windows-10, scheduled-tasks, uac

i recently moved all of my startup's that require admin privileges from `shell:startup` to tasks in Windows's Task Scheduler so they bypass UAC and i don't have to confirm 20 UAC windows on every login. Now i have the problem that my PC gets slowed down from these so much that it's constantly freezing and not reacting to my inputs. Do you might have any idea what could be the reason for that or how to fix it?

[image: Screenshot of my Task Scheduler Library]

If you need any additional info's to help me further, please let me know :)

Comment: "Do you might have any idea what could be the reason for that or how to fix it?" - You have way to many programs launching on their own. Even if you had a script that did it, you would still have to wait, for the script to start each application.  Considering cutting down on the applications that are ALWAYS launched when a user logs into their profile.

Comment: The "waiting for all tasks to start" process is not the problem, it's actually quite fast. The computer starts to have problems around 30 secs after everything was started. Back when i had the same amount of tasks set as autostart shortcut i didn't had that problems.

Comment: 30 seconds is about 100x as long as my startup. Most applications don't actually require Administrator permissions.  Is there a chance you are launching these applications as an Administrator, and they don't actually require, elevated permissions?

Comment: They do, and 30 secs are fine. My pc is from 2008

Comment: There's no way putty agent needs to run as admin.

Comment: You asked the reason it's taking so long (and complain about your system freezing)that's because each task is happening one by one and each one must wait for the previous task to finish.  You wanted to know way your Startup is taking so long (that's why)

Comment: Is there no way to tell the Task Scheduler to 'disconnect' from the task after it got executed? So it doesn't wait any longer